# Unable to install nvm on macOS 12.3

Tags: macos, zsh, nvm

I want to install [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) on my macOS 12.3.

The command I use to install nvm is `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`.

But the installation doesn't succeed. I got `zsh: command not found: nvm` error when running `nvm` command.

I use [iTerm](https://iterm2.com/) as my terminal.

I've read the [Troubleshooting on macOS](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-macos) section. And I've confirmed that I hav the following code in my `~/.zshrc` file:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

When I run `source ~/.zshrc`, I got the following error:

```
/Users/myname/.zshrc:124: condition expected: source
```

Line 124 of `~/.zshrc` is `[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm`.

I don't understand why the error occurs only when I use `source` command to execute `~/.zshrc`.

If I copy the 3 lines of code and paste them to iTerm, no error would occur. And I can successfully run `nvm` command after that.

Why does `source ~/.zshrc` create that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this problem is that my 122nd line of `~/.zshrc` is `[[  ]] && source <(kubectl completion zsh)`.

After changing that line to `source <(kubectl completion zsh)`, the problem is solved.

According to [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/included/optional-kubectl-configs-zsh/), if you want to install *zsh auto-completion* for kubernetes, adding `source <(kubectl completion zsh)` is enough.

Adding `[[  ]]` is redundant and cause errors.